# Reading from Database through multiple threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading data from vertica database using multiple threads in java. 
I have around 20 million records and I am opening 5 different threads having select queries like this....

```
start = threadnum;

while (start*20000<=totalRecords){

    select * from tableName order by colname limit 20000 offset start*20000.

    start +=5;

}
```

The above query assigns 20K distinct records to read from db to each thread.
for eg the first thread will read first 20k records then 20K records starting from 100 000 position,etc

But I am not getting performance improvement. In fact using a single thread if it takes x seconds to read 20 million records then it is taking almost x seconds for each thread to read from database.
Shouldn't there be some improvement from x seconds (was expecting x/5 seconds)?

Can anybody pinpoint what is going wrong?

Comment: Following this logic you just need to increase the number of threads by ``n`` to reduce the total processing time by ``1/n``.

Comment: The network isn't multi-threaded. You can use as many threads as you like but once you saturate the network, that's it, no further improvement possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your database presumably lies on a single disk; that disk is connected to a motherboard using a single data cable; if the database server is on a network, then it is connected to that network using a single network cable; so, there is just one path that all that data has to pass through before it can arrive at your different threads and be processed.

The result is, of course, bad performance.

The lesson to take home is this:

> Massive I/O from the same device can never be improved by multithreading.

To put it in different terms: parallelism never increases performance when the bottleneck is the transferring of the data, and all the data come from a single sequential source.

If you had 5 different databases stored on 5 different disks, that would work better.

If transferring the data was only taking half of the total time, and the other half of the time was consumed in doing computations with the data, then you would be able to halve the total time by desynchronizing the transferring from the processing, but that would require only 2 threads. (And halving the total time would be the best that you could achieve: more threads would not increase performance.)

---

As for why reading 20 thousand records appears to perform almost as bad as reading 20 million records, I am not sure why this is happening, but it could be due to a silly implementation of the database system that you are using.

What ***may*** be happening is that your database system is implementing the `offset` and `limit` clauses on the database driver, meaning that it implements them on the client instead of on the server. If this is in fact what is happening, then all 20 million records are being sent from the server to the client each time, and then the `offset` and `limit` clauses on the client throw most of them away and only give you the 20 thousand that you asked for.

You might think that you should be able to trick the system to work correctly by turning the query into a subquery nested inside another query, but my experience when I tried this a long time ago with some database system that I do not remember anymore is that it would result in an error saying that `offset` and `limit` cannot appear in a subquery, they must always appear in a top-level query.  (Precisely because the database driver needed to be able to do its incredibly counter-productive filtering on the client.)

Another approach would be to assign an incrementing unique integer id to each row which has no gaps in the numbering, so that you can `select ... where unique_id >= start and unique_id <= (start + 20000)` which will definitely be executed on the server rather than on the client.

However, as I wrote above, this will probably not allow you to achieve any increase in performance by parallelizing things, because you will still have to wait for a total of 20 million rows to be transmitted from the server to the client, and it does not matter whether this is done in one go or in 1000 gos of 20 thousand rows each. You cannot have two stream of rows simultaneously flying down a single wire.

Answer (score 1):

I will not repeat what Mike Nakis says as it is true and well explained :

> I/O from a physical disk cannot be improved by multithreading

Nevertheless I would like to add something.

When you execute a query like that :

```
 select * from tableName order by colname limit 20000 offset start*20000.
```

from the client side you may handle the result of the query that you could improve by using multiple threads.

But from the database side you have not the hand on the processing of the query and the Vertica database is probably designed to execute your query by performing parallel tasks according to the machine possibilities.

So from the client side you may split the execution of your query in one, two or three parallel threads, it should not change many things finally as a professional database is designed to optimize the response time according to the number of requests it receives and machine possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't get x/5 seconds.  You are not thinking about the fact that you are getting 5 times the number of records in the same amount of time.  It's about throughput, not about time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the following is a good solution.  It has worked for us to stream and process millions of records without much of a memory and processing overhead.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
pstmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
    // Do the thing
}
```

Using `OFFSET x LIMIT 20000` will result in the same query being executed again and again.  For 20 million records and for 20K records per execution, the query will get executed 1000 times.
`OFFSET 0 LIMIT 20000` will perform well, but `OFFSET 19980000 LIMIT 20000` itself will take a lot of time.  As the query will be executed fully and then from the top it will have to ignore 19980000 records and give the last 20000.

But using the `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` options and setting the fetch size to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` will result in the query being executed only ONCE and the records will be streamed in chunks, and can be processed in a single thread.